# Pass parameter value to button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to click button Day and to open report with parameter=1 and click button Week and see report with parameter=2. Here is my code

```
   @using Portal.Framework.Models;

<form id="reportParametersForm" method="GET" action="@string.Format("{0}/{1}", @Url.Content("~/Reports/View"), ViewBag.Report)">
    <fieldset style="padding: 0.2em 0 1.2em 0;height:60px">
        <legend style="margin: 0 1px 0 10px;padding: 3px 36px 3px 20px;background-color: #494949;color: white;font-size: 11pt;">
        @Html.Resource(String.Format("Report_{0}", ViewBag.Report as string))</legend>

    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding = "0" style="font-size:x-small">        
        <tr valign="bottom" style="height:10px">
           <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: top">
            </td>
            <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
                <label style="font-size:small">
                    Time period</label>

                <input type="hidden" id="dailyReportUrl" value = "@Url?ReportParameter=1" />       
                <input class="button" id="showDailyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Day" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />

                <input type="hidden" id="weeklyReportUrl" value = "@Url?ReportParameter=2" />       
                <input class="button" id="showWeeklyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Week" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />

            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#showDailyReport").click(function () {
            $("#weeklyReportPlaceholder").attr("src", "");
            $("#weeklyReportPlaceholder").attr("src", $("#dailyReportUrl").val());
        });

        $("#showWeeklyReport").click(function () {
            $("#weeklyReportPlaceholder").attr("src", "");
            $("#weeklyReportPlaceholder").attr("src", $("#weeklyReportUrl").val());
        });

    });

    function showDailyReport() {
        alert('daily');
    }

    function showWeekyReport() {
        alert('weekly');
    }

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClickHandler(elem) {
        elem.style.background = 'red';
        elem.style.color = 'white';
    }

</script>
```

Currently i get only for Day button, when i click on Week i get the same chart image from my report.
Plus how to make when i click some button to change color and when click other button to return original color of other buttons and change color of clicked button. So far i have this , but doesn't work, i get 2 changed buttons, changed color stands although i click other button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onClickHandler(elem) {
        elem.style.background = 'red';
        elem.style.color = 'white';
    }
</script>
```

How to take parameter value from report and pass to button when i click that button, an how to change color of only active button

Answer (score 0):

try This :

```
$('input.button').click(function(){
  $(this).css({'background-color' : 'red', 'color' :'white'})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hq09joLm/)

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="font-size:x-small">
    <tr valign="bottom" style="height:10px">
        <td width="20px" style="vertical-align: top"></td>
        <td width="30px" style="vertical-align: middle" align="center" nowrap="nowrap">
            <label style="font-size:small">Time period</label>
            <input type="hidden" id="dailyReportUrl" value="@Url?ReportParameter=1" />
            <input class="button" id="showDailyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Day" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />
            <input type="hidden" id="weeklyReportUrl" value="@Url?ReportParameter=2" />
            <input class="button" id="showWeeklyReport" name="searchQueue" type="submit" value="Week" onClick="onClickHandler(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    function onClickHandler(elem) {
        elem.style.background = 'red';
        elem.style.color = 'white';
    }
</script>
```